# How can I control the media volume while using the camera?

Tags: nexus-4, camera, volume-control

I just upgraded to a Nexus 4 and have discovered the behaviour of the volume controls has been overridden within the camera app.  The volume up button has been remapped to snap the camera shutter.  As I often listen to music on my phone, I find this a great inconvenience.

Is there a way to restore the action of the volume buttons to their default behaviour of controlling the media volume, or alternately is there any other way to control the media volume from within the camera app?

Comment: Sorry not an answer you're looking for but I've just learnt that I can use the volume buttons to take photos with my Galaxy Nexus, had it for nearly two years and had no idea that there was a really easy hardware button for this! Thanks